# UICollectionView: cellForItemIndexPath not called after insertItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios7.1

I have an UICollectionView showing UIImages. After the initial loading the collection view shows the image in the self.image rray (data source) correctly. The delegate and dataSource are set directly in the storyboard.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.images.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}
```

After adding a new image the update is not working. The method cellForItemIndexPath is not called. Any idea? The following code adds the new image. self.imgPhoto shows the selected image correctly. Therefore something with the UICollectionView should be wrong.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imgPhoto.image = chosenImage;
    [self.images addObject:chosenImage];
    [self.cvPhotos insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.images.count-1 inSection:0]]];

    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: insert: %lu %d", self.images.count-1, 0);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. For some reason the storyboard lost the link to cvPhotos. It was always nil. Therefore, the insertItemAtIndexPath method was not called.

But I received no error message. Is that correct when I call a method of an nil-object?